# Is it possible to run an XMPP server without a domain name?

Tags: xmpp

I need to run an XMPP server for IM with end-to-end encryption and voice calling. I'm trying to set up Prosody, but is it possible to run an XMPP server without a domain name? Without own DNS server and VPN network between clients?

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: **Yes.**

You can still configure a XMPP domain for your server. According to the standard, it doesn't has to be an DNS Name or IP address. Something like `myserver` is fine. Quoting [RFC 7622 § 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7622#section-3.2):

> The domainpart for every XMPP service MUST be a fully qualified domain
> name (FQDN), an IPv4 address, an IPv6 address, or an unqualified
> hostname (i.e., a text label that is resolvable on a local network).

But if you don't have a DNS name, then clients won't know automatically how to reach your server. Which means you have to configure the IP address and the port in every client.

Comment: Thank you, Flow. In my case, xmpp server with inner ip will be behind NAT with white ip. Will I have to forward ports only or something else to do? What about srv record?

Comment: Yes you will need some sort of port forwarding. SRV records map a DNS name to an host and a port. And that DNS name must match the XMPP domain name of your service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IP address instead of a domain name, but if that address will be changing on a regular basis, you'll probably need modifications to standard XMPP servers and clients, as they'll not be expecting that.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. IP is constant. And what I have to write in domain section in prosody config if I have no domain name?

Comment: You may not have a DNS name, but you still have a XMPP domain (which does not necessarily requires a matching DNS name, although I would recommend it). The XMPP domain can either be your IP address or an unqualified hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I went through many Prosody tutorials and I think it is not possible to set up server based only on IP address and using SSL. I even have not found how to configure Prosody on local network with SSL and resolvable name like raspberry.local. My client always gave server not found, or incorrect communication.